# Create a not final widget

Tags: flutter

I wonder is it possible to declare a widget then after that edit the properties in the widget. See example below:

```
InputDecoration temp = new InputDecoration(
  labelText: label,
  labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  // ...
);
```

and then

```
temp.suffixIcon = IconButton(icon: Icons.sth);
```

I can't seems to get it working as it return `suffixIcon` is final. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: no, but you can use a variable in your `StatefulWidget` , assign a IconButton there and refresh the widget

Answer (score 1):

No. That is not possible (or should be avoided as much as possible).

The reason for this is, the same widget can be inserted in multiple locations of the widget tree.

For example, it's totally reasonable to do:

```dart
Widget foo = Something();

return Row(
  children: [
    foo,
    foo,
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is imperative programming:
You have a program state and whenever it changes, you update all the necessary UI elements manually.

Flutter is a reactive UI framework. Semi-mathematically speaking, that means there is some state *s* and a build method *f* and when the state changes, the framework builds the new widget subtree by calling your function *f(s)*.

More specifically, you don't want to change the concrete attributes of your child widgets—you don't even want to be able to do that because that goes against the reactive paradigm. Rather change the state of the program and tell the framework that the state changed. It will then re-render all the child widgets with the new attributes.
Don't worry about performance too much, Flutter is heavily optimized in that regard.

Widgets with changing state are `StatefulWidget`s in Flutter. Every `StatefulWidget` has a corresponding `State`, which can also contain mutable (non-`final`) attributes like these:

```dart
bool _useFirstIcon = true;
```

When you change the state, use the `setState` function in the `State` like this to notify the framework about the change:

```dart
void _changeTheState() {
  setState(() => _useFirstIcon = false);
}
```

That tells the framework to re-render that subtree. Basically, it means your `build` method will be called when the next frame is drawn.
There, you should return different widget trees depending on the state (your `_useFirstIcon` attribute).

```dart
return SomeWidget(
  decoration: new InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: _useFirstIcon ? Icons.someIcon : Icons.someOtherIcon,
      onPressed: _changeTheState,
    ),
  ),
);
```

---

Note that sometimes, you do want to access the state of a widget from the parent widget. That is—arguably somewhat inelegantly—achieved by providing some sort of `controller` to the child widget and the child widget modifies the state of the controller to make parts of its own state accessible to the parent.
This architecture is for example used in the `TextField` using the `TextController`.